# Не видно текст внутри элемента

Tags: javascript, html, css

Использую [CropperJs](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs). Стоит задача - отобразить размеры вырезаемой области. В плагине не нашел такой функции, поэтому пишу сам. С помощью `createElement` и всяких не хитрых вычислений, создаю элемент и размещаю его в нужном месте.
Но вот проблема - текст (значения) не видны на экране, хотя есть в DOM. 
В чем может быть проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `font, font-size, line height` - не видно какие, и для этого скрина лучше бы подошел computedstyle

Comment: @StrangerintheQ - Вы гений. Проблема была в `font-size`. Час времени убил)

Comment: судя по тому что выше тоже используются span - наверное у них нулевой размер шрифта..

Comment: всегда смотрите `computed style`